# Como fazer um CRUD simples utilizando Temp-table

Tags: lógica, crud, progress-4gl

estou começando no Progress 4gl, e gostaria de aprender como faço um cadastro simples de clientes ou qualquer coisa relacionada um CRUD. gostaria de fazer utilizando temp-tables.  andei pesquisando e cheguei a isso, estou modificando mas ainda não cheguei no que eu queria.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt
FIELD a AS INT
FIELD b AS CHAR.

DEFINE BUTTON bt  LABEL "Modify".
DEFINE BUTTON btS LABEL "Save".


DEFINE QUERY qr FOR tt.
DEFINE BROWSE br QUERY qr DISPLAY tt.a tt.b WITH SIZE 60 BY 4 .


DEFINE FRAME f
    br bt
    tt.a SKIP tt.b btS WITH THREE-D SIDE-LABELS.

ON 'choose':U OF bt IN FRAME f
DO:
    RUN updateRecord.
END.

ON 'choose':U OF btS IN FRAME f DO:
    FIND FIRST tt WHERE tt.a = INPUT FRAME f tt.a NO-ERROR.
    ASSIGN tt.a = INPUT FRAME f tt.a
           tt.b = INPUT FRAME f tt.b.
    BROWSE br:REFRESH().
    CLEAR FRAME f.
END.

/* Create some test records */
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 1 b = 'first'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 2 b = 'second'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 3 b = 'third'.

OPEN QUERY qr FOR EACH tt.
ENABLE ALL EXCEPT tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.

WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF CURRENT-WINDOW.

PROCEDURE updateRecord:
    DISPLAY tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
    ENABLE  tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
END PROCEDURE.
```

se alguém puder ajudar, ou recomendar algum site pra me ajudar a aprender.

Comment: Coloca a tag da linguagem, assim o código fica com o highlight e assim o pessoal sabe de qual linguagem se trata

Comment: vlww, tentei colocar porem deu que eu não tinha pontos suficientes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui esta uma tela similar aquela que voce ja tinha, mas com create e delete. Eu desabilitei a chave (tt.a) no modificar, porque eh padrao nao deixar alterar a chave primaria, alem do que, o find que vc faz no salvar falha quando vc muda a chave.

O codigo:
    DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt
    FIELD a AS INT
    FIELD b AS CHAR.

```
DEFINE BUTTON bt   LABEL "Modify".
DEFINE BUTTON btS  LABEL "Save".
DEFINE BUTTON btC  LABEL "Close".
DEFINE BUTTON btD  LABEL "Delete".
DEFINE BUTTON btCr LABEL "Create".

DEFINE QUERY qr FOR tt.
DEFINE BROWSE br QUERY qr DISPLAY tt.a tt.b WITH SIZE 60 BY 5 .


DEFINE FRAME f
    br btCr SKIP 
       bt AT ROW 2 COL 62
       btD AT ROW 3 COL 62 
    tt.a AT ROW 6 COL 1 SKIP tt.b btS btC WITH THREE-D SIDE-LABELS.

ON 'choose':U OF bt IN FRAME f
DO:
    RUN updateRecord.
END.

ON 'CHOOSE':U OF btCr IN FRAME f DO:
    RUN createRecord.
END.

ON 'choose':U OF btS IN FRAME f DO:
    FIND FIRST tt WHERE tt.a = INPUT FRAME f tt.a NO-ERROR.
    IF NOT AVAILABLE tt THEN CREATE tt.
    ASSIGN tt.a = INPUT FRAME f tt.a
           tt.b = INPUT FRAME f tt.b.
    OPEN QUERY qr FOR EACH tt.
    CLEAR FRAME f.
    DISABLE tt.a tt.b.
END.

ON 'choose':U OF btD DO:
    MESSAGE 'Are you sure you want to delete?'
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX QUESTION BUTTONS YES-NO UPDATE lResp AS LOGICAL.
    IF lResp THEN DO:
       DELETE tt.
       OPEN QUERY qr FOR EACH tt.
    END.
END.

/* Create some test records */
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 1 b = 'first'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 2 b = 'second'.
CREATE tt. ASSIGN a = 3 b = 'third'.

OPEN QUERY qr FOR EACH tt.
ENABLE ALL EXCEPT tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
WAIT-FOR CHOOSE OF btC.


PROCEDURE updateRecord:
    DISPLAY tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
    ENABLE  tt.b WITH FRAME f.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE createRecord:
    ENABLE tt.a tt.b WITH FRAME f.
END PROCEDURE.
```

O problema eh que telas em CHUI (CHaracter User Interface) sao mais trabalhosas. Experimenta brincar com o appBuilder que fica mais bem acabado e mais facil. Quanto a sites de Progress, creio que poucos ainda estao ativos... Normalmente as pessoas ja trabalham na area e tem duvidas mais pontuais. mas quando for buscar ajuda, procure pelas tags progress 4gl, ABL ou OpenEdge.

Pelo seu codigo, vejo que voce domina alguns comandos, mas da pra explorar varios conceitos que voce talvez nao entenda ainda, ou nao saiba como funciona no Progress. Precisaria passar por um treinamento mesmo, pra alguem explicar diretamente.

Nao sei se recomendo voce tentar aprender o Progress basico hoje. Sugiro voce pegar o Telerik, que eh a plataforma mobile deles, e eh o que tem de mais novo, e que provavelmente vai ter bastante demanda logo.

Enfim, espero que ajude. Qualquer duvida eh soh falar.

Comment: entao pra falar a verdade nem queria aprender o progress kk mas preciso dele no trabalho, fiz alguns programas de relatorios pra excel mas so isso mesmo, eu entendo de java e c# progress é tipo muito novo pra min nem sabia que existia, tava usando o app builder mas eu to meio perdido, java ou c# quando tenho qualquer duvida rapidamente acho alguma solução na web ja progress ..

Comment: O Progress é uma boa linguagem pra desenvolver rápido, com várias vantagens em se ter uma linguagem integrada ao banco de dados. Mas se voce vem de OO, vai ter alguma dificuldade com linguagem estruturada. Nada impossível de se aprender, claro. Mas é um pouquinho diferente, o paradigma.

Answer (score 0):

andei mexendo no app builder e cheguei nisso porem ainda estou perdido, quero criar um cadastro simples adicionar informacoes em uma temp-table editar, excluir ou adicionar mais so isso, fiz uma telinha porem ainda não cheguei a nada

```
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _VERSION-NUMBER AB_v10r12 GUI
&ANALYZE-RESUME
&Scoped-define WINDOW-NAME C-Win
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CUSTOM _DEFINITIONS C-Win 


CREATE WIDGET-POOL.

/* ***************************  Definitions  ************************** */

/* Parameters Definitions ---                                           */

/* Local Variable Definitions ---                                       */

/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME


&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-PREPROCESSOR-BLOCK 

/* ********************  Preprocessor Definitions  ******************** */

&Scoped-define PROCEDURE-TYPE Window
&Scoped-define DB-AWARE no

/* Name of designated FRAME-NAME and/or first browse and/or first query */
&Scoped-define FRAME-NAME DEFAULT-FRAME

/* Standard List Definitions                                            */
&Scoped-Define ENABLED-OBJECTS BTCADAST FILLNOME BTLIST FILLSOBRENOME ~
BTALTERAR FILLCPF BTAPAGAR SELECT-1 
&Scoped-Define DISPLAYED-OBJECTS FILLNOME FILLSOBRENOME FILLCPF SELECT-1 

/* Custom List Definitions                                              */
/* List-1,List-2,List-3,List-4,List-5,List-6                            */

/* _UIB-PREPROCESSOR-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME



/* ***********************  Control Definitions  ********************** */
    DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt-usuario
    FIELD nome AS CHAR
    FIELD sobrenome AS CHAR
    FIELD cpf AS CHAR.

    DEFINE VAR nomelist AS CHAR.


/* Define the widget handle for the window                              */
DEFINE VAR C-Win AS WIDGET-HANDLE NO-UNDO.

/* Definitions of the field level widgets                               */
DEFINE BUTTON BTCADAST 
     LABEL "Cadastrar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.13.

DEFINE BUTTON BTLIST 
     LABEL "Listar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.13.

DEFINE BUTTON BTALTERAR 
     LABEL "Alterar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.13.

DEFINE BUTTON BTAPAGAR 
     LABEL "Apagar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILLNOME AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(25)":U 
     LABEL "Nome" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 24 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILLCPF AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(3).X(3).X(3)-X(2)":U 
     LABEL "CPF" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 24 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILLSOBRENOME AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     LABEL "Sobrenome" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 24 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE SELECT-1 AS CHARACTER 
     VIEW-AS SELECTION-LIST SINGLE SCROLLBAR-VERTICAL 
     SIZE 30 BY 7 NO-UNDO.


/* ************************  Frame Definitions  *********************** */

DEFINE FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
     BTCADAST AT ROW 2 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 2
     FILLNOME AT ROW 2 COL 45 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 10
     BTLIST AT ROW 4 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 4
     FILLSOBRENOME AT ROW 4 COL 45 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 14
     BTALTERAR AT ROW 6 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 6
     FILLCPF AT ROW 6 COL 45 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 12
     BTAPAGAR AT ROW 8 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 8
     SELECT-1 AT ROW 9 COL 41 NO-LABEL WIDGET-ID 16
    WITH 1 DOWN NO-BOX KEEP-TAB-ORDER OVERLAY 
         SIDE-LABELS NO-UNDERLINE THREE-D 
         AT COL 1 ROW 1
         SIZE 80 BY 16 WIDGET-ID 100.


/* *********************** Procedure Settings ************************ */

&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _PROCEDURE-SETTINGS
/* Settings for THIS-PROCEDURE
   Type: Window
   Allow: Basic,Browse,DB-Fields,Window,Query
   Other Settings: COMPILE
 */
&ANALYZE-RESUME _END-PROCEDURE-SETTINGS

/* *************************  Create Window  ************************** */

&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _CREATE-WINDOW
IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U THEN
  CREATE WINDOW C-Win ASSIGN
         HIDDEN             = YES
         TITLE              = "<insert window title>"
         HEIGHT             = 16
         WIDTH              = 80
         MAX-HEIGHT         = 16
         MAX-WIDTH          = 80
         VIRTUAL-HEIGHT     = 16
         VIRTUAL-WIDTH      = 80
         RESIZE             = yes
         SCROLL-BARS        = no
         STATUS-AREA        = no
         BGCOLOR            = ?
         FGCOLOR            = ?
         KEEP-FRAME-Z-ORDER = yes
         THREE-D            = yes
         MESSAGE-AREA       = no
         SENSITIVE          = yes.
ELSE {&WINDOW-NAME} = CURRENT-WINDOW.
/* END WINDOW DEFINITION                                                */
&ANALYZE-RESUME



/* ***********  Runtime Attributes and AppBuilder Settings  *********** */

&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _RUN-TIME-ATTRIBUTES
/* SETTINGS FOR WINDOW C-Win
  VISIBLE,,RUN-PERSISTENT                                               */
/* SETTINGS FOR FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   FRAME-NAME                                                           */
IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
THEN C-Win:HIDDEN = no.

/* _RUN-TIME-ATTRIBUTES-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME





/* ************************  Control Triggers  ************************ */

&Scoped-define SELF-NAME C-Win
&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CONTROL C-Win C-Win
ON END-ERROR OF C-Win /* <insert window title> */
OR ENDKEY OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE DO:
  /* This case occurs when the user presses the "Esc" key.
     In a persistently run window, just ignore this.  If we did not, the
     application would exit. */
  IF THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.

/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME


&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CONTROL C-Win C-Win
ON WINDOW-CLOSE OF C-Win /* <insert window title> */
DO:
  /* This event will close the window and terminate the procedure.  */
  APPLY "CLOSE":U TO THIS-PROCEDURE.
  RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.

/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME


&UNDEFINE SELF-NAME

&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _CUSTOM _MAIN-BLOCK C-Win 


/* ***************************  Main Block  *************************** */

CREATE tt-usuario. 
    ASSIGN 
        nome = FILLNOME
        sobrenome = FILLSOBRENOME
        cpf = FILLCPF.

OPEN QUERY qr FOR EACH tt-usuario.
ENABLE ALL EXCEPT tt-usuario.nome tt-usuario.sobrenome tt-usuario.cpf WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME.


ON CHOOSE OF BTCADAST IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* botao cadastrar */
    MESSAGE "Digite o nome para cadastrar."        
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.    


ON CHOOSE OF BTLIST IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* botao listar */

ON CHOOSE OF BTALTERAR IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* botao alterar */
    MESSAGE "Alterar."        
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.

ON CHOOSE OF BTAPAGAR IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* botao apagar */
     MESSAGE "Deseja apagar."        
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX QUESTION BUTTONS YES-NO-CANCEL.

/* Set CURRENT-WINDOW: this will parent dialog-boxes and frames.        */
ASSIGN CURRENT-WINDOW                = {&WINDOW-NAME} 
       THIS-PROCEDURE:CURRENT-WINDOW = {&WINDOW-NAME}.

/* The CLOSE event can be used from inside or outside the procedure to  */
/* terminate it.                                                        */
ON CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE 
   RUN disable_UI.

/* Best default for GUI applications is...                              */
PAUSE 0 BEFORE-HIDE.

/* Now enable the interface and wait for the exit condition.            */
/* (NOTE: handle ERROR and END-KEY so cleanup code will always fire.    */
MAIN-BLOCK:
DO ON ERROR   UNDO MAIN-BLOCK, LEAVE MAIN-BLOCK
   ON END-KEY UNDO MAIN-BLOCK, LEAVE MAIN-BLOCK:
  RUN enable_UI.
  IF NOT THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN
    WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE.
END.

/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME


/* **********************  Internal Procedures  *********************** */


&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _PROCEDURE disable_UI C-Win  _DEFAULT-DISABLE
PROCEDURE disable_UI :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     DISABLE the User Interface
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       Here we clean-up the user-interface by deleting
               dynamic widgets we have created and/or hide 
               frames.  This procedure is usually called when
               we are ready to "clean-up" after running.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Delete the WINDOW we created */
  IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
  THEN DELETE WIDGET C-Win.
  IF THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN DELETE PROCEDURE THIS-PROCEDURE.
END PROCEDURE.

/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME

&ANALYZE-SUSPEND _UIB-CODE-BLOCK _PROCEDURE enable_UI C-Win  _DEFAULT-ENABLE
PROCEDURE enable_UI :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     ENABLE the User Interface
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       Here we display/view/enable the widgets in the
               user-interface.  In addition, OPEN all queries
               associated with each FRAME and BROWSE.
               These statements here are based on the "Other 
               Settings" section of the widget Property Sheets.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  DISPLAY FILLNOME FILLSOBRENOME FILLCPF SELECT-1 
      WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  ENABLE BTCADAST FILLNOME BTLIST FILLSOBRENOME BTALTERAR FILLCPF BTAPAGAR 
         SELECT-1 
      WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  {&OPEN-BROWSERS-IN-QUERY-DEFAULT-FRAME}
  VIEW C-Win.
END PROCEDURE.

/* _UIB-CODE-BLOCK-END */
&ANALYZE-RESUME
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, estamos fugindo completamente do escopo do site, mas melhorei a janela pra vc, deve funcionar como vc planejou agora. Qualquer dúvida fala aí.

```
/* Connected Databases 
*/
&Scoped-define WINDOW-NAME C-Win
CREATE WIDGET-POOL.

/* ***************************  Definitions  ************************** */

/* Parameters Definitions ---                                           */

/* Local Variable Definitions ---                                       */

DEFINE VARIABLE cAction AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt-usuario
    FIELD nome      AS CHARACTER 
    FIELD sobrenome AS CHARACTER
    FIELD cpf AS CHARACTER FORMAT "999-999-999-99"
    INDEX idxNomeSobreNome IS PRIMARY nome sobrenome
    INDEX idxcpf IS UNIQUE cpf.



/* ********************  Preprocessor Definitions  ******************** */

&Scoped-define PROCEDURE-TYPE Window
&Scoped-define DB-AWARE no

/* Name of designated FRAME-NAME and/or first browse and/or first query */
&Scoped-define FRAME-NAME DEFAULT-FRAME
&Scoped-define BROWSE-NAME brUsuario

/* Internal Tables (found by Frame, Query & Browse Queries)             */
&Scoped-define INTERNAL-TABLES tt-usuario

/* Definitions for BROWSE brUsuario                                     */
&Scoped-define FIELDS-IN-QUERY-brUsuario tt-usuario.nome tt-usuario.sobrenome tt-usuario.cpf   
&Scoped-define ENABLED-FIELDS-IN-QUERY-brUsuario   
&Scoped-define SELF-NAME brUsuario
&Scoped-define QUERY-STRING-brUsuario FOR EACH tt-usuario
&Scoped-define OPEN-QUERY-brUsuario OPEN QUERY {&SELF-NAME} FOR EACH tt-usuario.
&Scoped-define TABLES-IN-QUERY-brUsuario tt-usuario
&Scoped-define FIRST-TABLE-IN-QUERY-brUsuario tt-usuario


/* Definitions for FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME                                  */
&Scoped-define OPEN-BROWSERS-IN-QUERY-DEFAULT-FRAME ~
    ~{&OPEN-QUERY-brUsuario}

/* Standard List Definitions                                            */
&Scoped-Define ENABLED-OBJECTS BTCADAST BTLIST BTALTERAR brUsuario BTAPAGAR 
&Scoped-Define DISPLAYED-OBJECTS FILLNOME FILLSOBRENOME FILLCPF 

/* Custom List Definitions                                              */
/* List-1,List-2,List-3,List-4,List-5,List-6                            */

/* ***********************  Control Definitions  ********************** */

/* Define the widget handle for the window                              */
DEFINE VAR C-Win AS WIDGET-HANDLE NO-UNDO.

/* Definitions of the field level widgets                               */
DEFINE BUTTON BTALTERAR 
     LABEL "Alterar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.14.

DEFINE BUTTON BTAPAGAR 
     LABEL "Apagar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.

DEFINE BUTTON BTCADAST 
     LABEL "Cadastrar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.14.

DEFINE BUTTON btCancel 
     LABEL "Cancelar" 
     SIZE 20 BY .95.

DEFINE BUTTON BTLIST 
     LABEL "Listar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.14.

DEFINE BUTTON btSave 
     LABEL "Salvar" 
     SIZE 20 BY 1.14.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILLCPF AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(3).X(3).X(3)-X(2)":U 
     LABEL "CPF" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 24 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILLNOME AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(25)":U 
     LABEL "Nome" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 24 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE FILLSOBRENOME AS CHARACTER FORMAT "X(256)":U 
     LABEL "Sobrenome" 
     VIEW-AS FILL-IN 
     SIZE 24 BY 1 NO-UNDO.

/* Query definitions                                                    */
DEFINE QUERY brUsuario FOR 
      tt-usuario SCROLLING.

/* Browse definitions                                                   */
DEFINE BROWSE brUsuario
  QUERY brUsuario DISPLAY
      tt-usuario.nome
     tt-usuario.sobrenome
     tt-usuario.cpf
    WITH NO-ROW-MARKERS SEPARATORS SIZE 41 BY 5.48 FIT-LAST-COLUMN.


/* ************************  Frame Definitions  *********************** */

DEFINE FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
     BTCADAST AT ROW 2 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 2
     FILLNOME AT ROW 2 COL 45 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 10
     BTLIST AT ROW 4 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 4
     FILLSOBRENOME AT ROW 4 COL 45 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 14
     BTALTERAR AT ROW 6 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 6
     FILLCPF AT ROW 6 COL 45 COLON-ALIGNED WIDGET-ID 12
     brUsuario AT ROW 7.9 COL 36 WIDGET-ID 200
     BTAPAGAR AT ROW 8 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 8
     btSave AT ROW 10.29 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 18
     btCancel AT ROW 12.43 COL 11 WIDGET-ID 20
    WITH 1 DOWN NO-BOX KEEP-TAB-ORDER OVERLAY 
         SIDE-LABELS NO-UNDERLINE THREE-D 
         AT COL 1 ROW 1 SCROLLABLE  WIDGET-ID 100.


/* *********************** Procedure Settings ************************ */

/* Settings for THIS-PROCEDURE
   Type: Window
   Allow: Basic,Browse,DB-Fields,Window,Query
   Other Settings: COMPILE
 */

/* *************************  Create Window  ************************** */

IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U THEN
  CREATE WINDOW C-Win ASSIGN
         HIDDEN             = YES
         TITLE              = "<insert window title>"
         HEIGHT             = 17.76
         WIDTH              = 92.8
         MAX-HEIGHT         = 17.76
         MAX-WIDTH          = 92.8
         VIRTUAL-HEIGHT     = 17.76
         VIRTUAL-WIDTH      = 92.8
         RESIZE             = yes
         SCROLL-BARS        = no
         STATUS-AREA        = no
         BGCOLOR            = ?
         FGCOLOR            = ?
         KEEP-FRAME-Z-ORDER = yes
         THREE-D            = yes
         MESSAGE-AREA       = no
         SENSITIVE          = yes.
ELSE {&WINDOW-NAME} = CURRENT-WINDOW.
/* END WINDOW DEFINITION                                                */



/* ***********  Runtime Attributes and AppBuilder Settings  *********** */

/* SETTINGS FOR WINDOW C-Win
  VISIBLE,,RUN-PERSISTENT                                               */
/* SETTINGS FOR FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   FRAME-NAME Size-to-Fit                                               */
/* BROWSE-TAB brUsuario FILLCPF DEFAULT-FRAME */
ASSIGN 
       FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME:SCROLLABLE       = FALSE.

/* SETTINGS FOR BUTTON btCancel IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   NO-ENABLE                                                            */
/* SETTINGS FOR BUTTON btSave IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   NO-ENABLE                                                            */
/* SETTINGS FOR FILL-IN FILLCPF IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   NO-ENABLE                                                            */
/* SETTINGS FOR FILL-IN FILLNOME IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   NO-ENABLE                                                            */
/* SETTINGS FOR FILL-IN FILLSOBRENOME IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME
   NO-ENABLE                                                            */
IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
THEN C-Win:HIDDEN = no.



/* Setting information for Queries and Browse Widgets fields            */

/* Query rebuild information for BROWSE brUsuario
     _START_FREEFORM
OPEN QUERY {&SELF-NAME} FOR EACH tt-usuario.
     _END_FREEFORM
     _Query            is OPENED
*/  /* BROWSE brUsuario */





/* ************************  Control Triggers  ************************ */

&Scoped-define SELF-NAME C-Win
ON END-ERROR OF C-Win /* <insert window title> */
OR ENDKEY OF {&WINDOW-NAME} ANYWHERE DO:
  /* This case occurs when the user presses the "Esc" key.
     In a persistently run window, just ignore this.  If we did not, the
     application would exit. */
  IF THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.


ON WINDOW-CLOSE OF C-Win /* <insert window title> */
DO:
  /* This event will close the window and terminate the procedure.  */
  APPLY "CLOSE":U TO THIS-PROCEDURE.
  RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME BTALTERAR
ON CHOOSE OF BTALTERAR IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Alterar */
DO:
  IF NOT AVAILABLE tt-usuario THEN RETURN NO-APPLY.

  ASSIGN fillnome = tt-usuario.nome
         fillsobrenome = tt-usuario.sobrenome
         fillcpf = tt-usuario.cpf.
  DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:
     DISPLAY fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf .
     ENABLE fillNome fillSobrenome btSave btCancel.
     DISABLE btCadast btList btAlterar btApagar.
  END.
  ASSIGN cAction = 'u'.
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME BTAPAGAR
ON CHOOSE OF BTAPAGAR IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Apagar */
DO:
  IF AVAILABLE tt-usuario THEN DO:
     MESSAGE "Deletar?" 
         VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX QUESTION BUTTONS YES-NO UPDATE lAns AS LOGICAL.
     IF lAns THEN do:
        DELETE tt-usuario.
        {&open-query-{&browse-name}}
     END.

  END.
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME BTCADAST
ON CHOOSE OF BTCADAST IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Cadastrar */
DO:
  DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:
     DISABLE btCadast btAlterar btList btApagar.
     ENABLE fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf btSave btCancel.
     ASSIGN cAction = 'N'. /* New */
  END.
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME btCancel
ON CHOOSE OF btCancel IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Cancelar */
DO:
  RUN clearFields.
  ENABLE btCadast btList btAlterar btApagar WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.
  DISABLE btSave btCancel fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME BTLIST
ON CHOOSE OF BTLIST IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Listar */
DO:
  {&open-query-{&browse-name}}
END.


&Scoped-define SELF-NAME btSave
ON CHOOSE OF btSave IN FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME /* Salvar */
DO:
  CASE cAction:
      WHEN 'N' THEN RUN newRecord.
      WHEN 'U' THEN RUN updateRecord.
      OTHERWISE 
         MESSAGE 'Opcao Invalida'
             VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
  END CASE.
  ASSIGN cAction = ''.
  DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:
     DISABLE fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf. 
     RUN clearFields.
  END.
  ENABLE btCadast btList btAlterar btApagar WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.
  DISABLE btSave btCancel WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.
END.


&Scoped-define BROWSE-NAME brUsuario
&UNDEFINE SELF-NAME



/* ***************************  Main Block  *************************** */


/* Set CURRENT-WINDOW: this will parent dialog-boxes and frames.        */
ASSIGN CURRENT-WINDOW                = {&WINDOW-NAME} 
       THIS-PROCEDURE:CURRENT-WINDOW = {&WINDOW-NAME}.

/* The CLOSE event can be used from inside or outside the procedure to  */
/* terminate it.                                                        */
ON CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE 
   RUN disable_UI.

/* Best default for GUI applications is...                              */
PAUSE 0 BEFORE-HIDE.

/* Now enable the interface and wait for the exit condition.            */
/* (NOTE: handle ERROR and END-KEY so cleanup code will always fire.    */
MAIN-BLOCK:
DO ON ERROR   UNDO MAIN-BLOCK, LEAVE MAIN-BLOCK
   ON END-KEY UNDO MAIN-BLOCK, LEAVE MAIN-BLOCK:
  RUN enable_UI.
  IF NOT THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN
    WAIT-FOR CLOSE OF THIS-PROCEDURE.
END.


/* **********************  Internal Procedures  *********************** */

PROCEDURE clearFields :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
ASSIGN fillnome = '' fillsobrenome = '' fillcpf = ''.
DISP fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE disable_UI :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     DISABLE the User Interface
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       Here we clean-up the user-interface by deleting
               dynamic widgets we have created and/or hide 
               frames.  This procedure is usually called when
               we are ready to "clean-up" after running.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Delete the WINDOW we created */
  IF SESSION:DISPLAY-TYPE = "GUI":U AND VALID-HANDLE(C-Win)
  THEN DELETE WIDGET C-Win.
  IF THIS-PROCEDURE:PERSISTENT THEN DELETE PROCEDURE THIS-PROCEDURE.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE enable_UI :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     ENABLE the User Interface
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       Here we display/view/enable the widgets in the
               user-interface.  In addition, OPEN all queries
               associated with each FRAME and BROWSE.
               These statements here are based on the "Other 
               Settings" section of the widget Property Sheets.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  DISPLAY FILLNOME FILLSOBRENOME FILLCPF 
      WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  ENABLE BTCADAST BTLIST BTALTERAR brUsuario BTAPAGAR 
      WITH FRAME DEFAULT-FRAME IN WINDOW C-Win.
  {&OPEN-BROWSERS-IN-QUERY-DEFAULT-FRAME}
  VIEW C-Win.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE newRecord :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:
   ASSIGN fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf .
END.
FIND tt-usuario WHERE tt-usuario.cpf = fillcpf NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE tt-usuario THEN
   MESSAGE 'Ja existe'
       VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
ELSE DO:
   CREATE tt-usuario.
   ASSIGN tt-usuario.nome      = fillnome
          tt-usuario.sobrenome = fillsobrenome
          tt-usuario.cpf       = fillcpf.
   {&open-query-{&browse-name}}
END.
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE updateRecord :
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purpose:     
  Parameters:  <none>
  Notes:       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DO WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}:
   ASSIGN fillnome fillsobrenome fillcpf .
END.
FIND tt-usuario WHERE tt-usuario.cpf = fillcpf NO-ERROR.
IF AVAILABLE tt-usuario THEN DO:
   ASSIGN tt-usuario.nome      = fillnome
          tt-usuario.sobrenome = fillsobrenome
          tt-usuario.cpf       = fillcpf.
   {&open-query-{&browse-name}}
END.
ELSE 
   MESSAGE 'Nao encontrado'
       VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.


END PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: cara vlwww ajuda muito ver algo funcionando pra ver no que eu to pensando errado, ajuda na logica, meu chefe fala toda hora que nao é orientado a objeto mas isso buga a mente, rsrsrs  mas to conseguindo entender ao poucos

Comment: Não é orientado a objeto mesmo. Se for orientado a alguma coisa, então é orientado a evento. Mas em geral no Progress o que você tem que lembrar é que as triggers são os trechos de código que são disparados pelos eventos dos componentes em tela. Em vários lugares você vai ler objetos em tela. Eu prefiro não pensar neles como objetos.